# Отправить пользователя в определенную область экрана

Tags: html, jquery

Для примера возьмём социальную сеть ВКонтакте. Страница пользователя на которой множество записей.

В ссылке передаётся идентификатор записи ввиде хэштега. К примеру, http://example.com/denis.nebesnii#489

Как при открытие страницы направить пользователя на запись с идентификатором указанным в ссылке? Т.е чтобы исключить скроллинг до записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На нужной записи добавить "якорь".

```
<div id="n145">...</div>
```

Сама ссылка будет выглядеть так

```
Сайт.рф#n145
```